# Cross-Domain ImageData Retrieval with Firefox Add-on SDK

Tags: javascript, firefox, canvas, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a Firefox add-on and it involves reading the pixel image data off of arbitrary images on the web.

With Chrome, Safari, and Opera, this is as simple as loading the image on a canvas in the background page (getImageData works and ignores same-origin restriction). But on Firefox, using the add-on SDK, creating a ["trusted" page-worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker#Scripting_trusted_page_content) and calling getImageData on images loaded from arbitrary URLs yields a security errors.

```
- message = The operation is insecure.
- name = SecurityError
- result = 2152923154
```

I've been flipping through the documentation for the Add-on SDK and from other StackOverflow answers, and it seems that content scripts are typically still bound by the same-origin policy. The PrivilegeManager/enablePrivilege (I'm not even sure this is relevant) seems to have been deprecated.

The only way I can currently imagine is the low-level net/xhr [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Low-Level_APIs/net_xhr) API with a requestType of Blob and loading the image with a createObjectURL. But this seems a bit unnecessarily convoluted, when I feel like there should be some way to just call getImageData without bumping against the same-origin-policy in a privileged context.

Answer (score 3):

What you need is a privileged `canvas`, and I don't think there is way to get one from a content script, trusted or not.

Still, we 're not out of options.

```js
var chromewin = require('sdk/windows/utils').getHiddenWindow();
var canvas = chromewin.document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
                                                'canvas');
var img = new chromewin.Image;
```

Now you can work without security restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

try `var blah = new Image` then do `blah.onload = function() { canvas.data...... }` then do `blah.src = '....'`